# Draw trajectory arc predictor in game

Tags: unity, c#, projectile-physics, curves

I found this tutorial on youtube and it works pretty well, but I want to add more to it.

How can I draw a smooth arc path in the game view (right now the path is only visible in the editor)?

Here is the code:

```
public class BallLauncher : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Rigidbody ball;
    public Transform target;

    public float h = 25;
    public float gravity = -18;

    public bool debugPath;

    void Start() {
        ball.useGravity = false;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
            Launch ();
        }

        if (debugPath) {
            DrawPath ();
        }
    }

    void Launch() {
        Physics.gravity = Vector3.up * gravity;
        ball.useGravity = true;
        ball.velocity = CalculateLaunchData ().initialVelocity;
    }

    LaunchData CalculateLaunchData() {
        float displacementY = target.position.y - ball.position.y;
        Vector3 displacementXZ = new Vector3 (target.position.x - ball.position.x, 0, target.position.z - ball.position.z);
        float time = Mathf.Sqrt(-2*h/gravity) + Mathf.Sqrt(2*(displacementY - h)/gravity);
        Vector3 velocityY = Vector3.up * Mathf.Sqrt (-2 * gravity * h);
        Vector3 velocityXZ = displacementXZ / time;

        return new LaunchData(velocityXZ + velocityY * -Mathf.Sign(gravity), time);
    }

    void DrawPath() {
        LaunchData launchData = CalculateLaunchData ();
        Vector3 previousDrawPoint = ball.position;

        int resolution = 30;
        for (int i = 1; i <= resolution; i++) {
            float simulationTime = i / (float)resolution * launchData.timeToTarget;
            Vector3 displacement = launchData.initialVelocity * simulationTime + Vector3.up *gravity * simulationTime * simulationTime / 2f;
            Vector3 drawPoint = ball.position + displacement;
            Debug.DrawLine (previousDrawPoint, drawPoint, Color.green);
            previousDrawPoint = drawPoint;
        }
    }

    struct LaunchData {
        public readonly Vector3 initialVelocity;
        public readonly float timeToTarget;

        public LaunchData (Vector3 initialVelocity, float timeToTarget)
        {
            this.initialVelocity = initialVelocity;
            this.timeToTarget = timeToTarget;
        }

    }
}
```

I found a way to Instantiate projectile along the path. Now I just need to know how to convert that line in debug mode to make it visible in game mode

Comment: `Debug.DrawLine` as the name says, only draws the lines in debug mode (editor). Use the linerenderer,

Comment: @Bálint with a little guidance about how to convert the DrawLine code to LineRenderer, this could make a solid answer. :)

Comment: ok, so you think i should make another post for instantiate projectiles along that path?

Comment: @DMGregory I have 0 experience with the line renderer apart from knowing it exists. I posted the comment to 1.) nudge future answerers in a direction and 2.) make sure OP either doesn't know about line renderers or can't use them yet. Although here it's unlikely, it can usually help rule out the most obvious solutions in case they can't use them for some reason

Comment: This is for 2D, shouldn't be hard to convert to 3D: https://github.com/starikcetin/Eflatun.Trajectory/blob/master/Eflatun.Trajectory/Packages/com.eflatun.trajectory/TrajectoryDrawer2D.cs

Answer (score 1):

This draws a lineRenderer instead of Debug:

```
public Rigidbody ball;
public Transform target;
public float h = 25;
public float gravity = -18;

public bool debugPath;

// Added Code 
public LineRenderer lineRenderer;

void Start() {
    ball.useGravity = false;

    // Added Code 
    lineRenderer.transform.position = ball.transform.position;
}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
        Launch ();
    }
    if(debugPath)
        DrawPath ();
}

void Launch() {
    Physics.gravity = Vector3.up * gravity;
    ball.useGravity = true;
    ball.velocity = CalculateLaunchData ().initialVelocity;
}

LaunchData CalculateLaunchData() {
    float displacementY = target.position.y - ball.position.y;
    Vector3 displacementXZ = new Vector3 (target.position.x - ball.position.x, 0, target.position.z - ball.position.z);
    float time = Mathf.Sqrt(-2*h/gravity) + Mathf.Sqrt(2*(displacementY - h)/gravity);
    Vector3 velocityY = Vector3.up * Mathf.Sqrt (-2 * gravity * h);
    Vector3 velocityXZ = displacementXZ / time;

    return new LaunchData(velocityXZ + velocityY * -Mathf.Sign(gravity), time);
}

void DrawPath() {
    LaunchData launchData = CalculateLaunchData ();

    // Added Code 
    lineRenderer.positionCount = 1;
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, ball.position);


    int resolution = 30;
    for (int i = 1; i <= resolution; i++) {
        float simulationTime = i / (float)resolution * launchData.timeToTarget;
        Vector3 displacement = launchData.initialVelocity * simulationTime + Vector3.up *gravity * simulationTime * simulationTime / 2f;
        Vector3 drawPoint = ball.position + displacement;

        // Added Code 
        lineRenderer.positionCount ++;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount-1, drawPoint);
    }
}

struct LaunchData {
    public readonly Vector3 initialVelocity;
    public readonly float timeToTarget;

    public LaunchData (Vector3 initialVelocity, float timeToTarget)
    {
        this.initialVelocity = initialVelocity;
        this.timeToTarget = timeToTarget;
    }

}
```